# Uppercase a RegExp Replace Capture Group in Google Big Query

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery, regexp-replace

I'm trying to do something very simple that has become quite complicated in Big Query. I want to convert things like a persons name to proper case (first letter of each word uppercase).

Here's the query i'm currently working on, and it ALMOST works!

```sql
SELECT 
REGEXP_REPLACE(
    CONCAT(
        UPPER(LEFT('tESt ing', 1)), 
        LOWER(SUBSTR('tESt ing', 2))
    ),
    ' ([a-z])', 
    UPPER(' \\1')
);

#outputs: Test ing
#desired output: Test Ing
```

For some reason the captured group doesn't get processed by UPPER.
If I put other text in with it it all goes to uppercase but the cap group variable stays lowercase.

Any help is much appreciated on this. It seems strange that this doesn't work as expected (maybe an order of operations thing...). Anyway, thanks in advance.

Eric

Answer (score 2):

So I first tried a laborious but (I think) straightforward approach:

```
SELECT
CONCAT(
    UPPER(LEFT('tESt ing', 1)), 
    LOWER(REGEXP_EXTRACT(SUBSTR('tESt ing', 2), r'(\w* )')),
    UPPER(REGEXP_EXTRACT(SUBSTR('tESt ing', 2), r' (\w)')),
    LOWER(REGEXP_EXTRACT(SUBSTR('tESt ing', 2), r' \w(.*)'))
);
```

which does seem to work and return `Test Ing` as desired.

Then I tried some simplifications to (I hope) reduce the workload a bit:

```
SELECT
CONCAT(
    UPPER(LEFT('tESt ing', 1)), 
    LOWER(REGEXP_EXTRACT('tESt ing', r'.(\w* )')),
    UPPER(REGEXP_EXTRACT('tESt ing', r' (\w)')),
    LOWER(REGEXP_EXTRACT('tESt ing', r' \w(.*)'))
);
```

and this also seems to work (same output).  However it only removes the `SUBSTR` calls -- not the regexp operations which I fear may be costlier.

Still, thought this may be worth sharing.

Comment: Certainly more resource effective, but that is because it only works on two words. This does not make it flexible and usable. What if for instance a user has a middle name? Also, I'd like something that can be used on longer strings.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but it seems the regular expression gets evaluated after the string operations within it.

As an alternative, try SPLIT():

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(capw, ' ') capitalized_name, FIRST(x) x, id
FROM (
  SELECT UPPER(LEFT(w, 1)) + LOWER(SUBSTR(w, 2)) capw, x, POSITION(w) pos, id
  FROM (
    SELECT SPLIT(x, ' ') w, id
    FROM (SELECT 'name lastname' x, 1 id), (SELECT 'name other name' x, 2 id), (SELECT 'a b c' x, 3 id), (SELECT 'name lastname' x, 4 id) 
  )
  ORDER BY pos
)
GROUP BY id
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to perform well in a real world use case. I'm getting Error: Resources exceeded during query execution.

Comment: This was tested on a table with about 15 Million rows.

Comment: Makes sense - I'm not sure how to optimize this for a bigger table. 2 alternatives: In the future, you'll be able to write your own JS functions inside BigQuery SQL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TYA6hy44Jo. In the present, you could externalize the process through the BigQuery to Hadoop connector: https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/bigquery-connector.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way that might scale better - can you test it on your 15 million record names dataset?

```
SELECT capitalized_name, x, id FROM (
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(capw, ' ')  OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY pos) capitalized_name, x, id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY pos DESC) rn
FROM (
  SELECT UPPER(LEFT(w, 1)) + LOWER(SUBSTR(w, 2)) capw, x, POSITION(w) pos, id
  FROM (
    SELECT SPLIT(rdf_schema_label, ' ') w, rdf_schema_label x, URI id
    FROM [dbpedia2014temp.Person]
  )
  ORDER BY pos
)
) WHERE rn=1
```

Comment: still getting resources exceeded

Answer (score -3):

REGEX_REPLACE is not a MySQL function, It must be implemented.
Here is one function named ucwords doing this :

```
    DELIMITER ||

CREATE FUNCTION `ucwords`( str VARCHAR(128) ) RETURNS varchar(128) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
DECLARE c CHAR(1);
DECLARE s VARCHAR(128);
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE bool INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE punct CHAR(17) DEFAULT ' ()[]{},.-_!@;:?/';
SET s = LCASE( str );
WHILE i < LENGTH( str ) DO
BEGIN
SET c = SUBSTRING( s, i, 1 );
IF LOCATE( c, punct ) > 0 THEN
SET bool = 1;
ELSEIF bool=1 THEN
BEGIN
IF c >= 'a' AND c <= 'z' THEN
BEGIN
SET s = CONCAT(LEFT(s,i-1),UCASE(c),SUBSTRING(s,i+1));
SET bool = 0;
END;
ELSEIF c >= '0' AND c <= '9' THEN
SET bool = 0;
END IF;
END;
END IF;
SET i = i+1;
END;
END WHILE;
RETURN s;
END ||

DELIMITER ;
```

Then you can use : SELECT ucwords('tEst iNg') from dual  => Test Ing

Comment: This is a question about Google BigQuery, not MySQL.